# Почему я не вижу объект в UV Editing?

Tags: blender

Default:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UV-Editing:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файлы: [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64a6oroq8tpf2xs/Fence3.blend?dl=0) и [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5du3bv4fghke4xk/Fence3.blend1?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часть объектов находится на другом слое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки слоев для каждого рабочего пространства свои